# Different DB use per request node js mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an app who need`s to support requests from different domains.
The code for all the domains need to be the same but different Databases.
I have a warping class for the Mongodb client witch gives the models the Connection.
Is there a way to get the domain name of the request inside this class without sending it from any call to that function(i have a lot of calls in different services)
please look at the comment at the getDb function to understand my need

Thanks

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb')
const assert = require('assert');

let MongoInstance = null;

class Mongo {

    constructor(connectionString = null, connectionOptions = {}) {
        if (MongoInstance === null) {
            MongoInstance = this;
        }
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
        this.connectionOptions = connectionOptions;
        this._db = {};

        return MongoInstance;
    }

    buildConnectionString() {
        if (this.connectionString !== null) {
            return;
        }
        this.connectionString = 'mongodb://';
        this.connectionString += process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME ? `${process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@` : '';
        this.connectionString += process.env.MONGODB_HOST;
        this.connectionString += process.env.MONGODB_PORT ? process.env.MONGODB_PORT : "";
    }

    connectToServer() {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.buildConnectionString();
            MongoClient.connect(this.connectionString, this.connectionOptions, (err, db) => {
                if (err) {
                   return reject(err);
                }
                process.env.MONGODB_LIST.split(",").forEach(dbName =>{
                    this._db[dbName] = db.db(dbName);
                }) 
               
                resolve(true)
            });
        })

    }

    getDb() {
        // how to discover the dbName without sending it to the function. (maybe a middleware)? 
        return this._db[dbName];
    }

    closeConnection() {
        this._db.close();
    }
}


module.exports = Mongo;
```